# No packages found in the current package source

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, c3.js

I am new to programming field. I am trying to install some nuget packages. but, I am getting this above message. Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 1):

```
    Got to Tools -> NuGet package manager -> Package manager Settings  -> Expand  NuGet Package manager  from left side Menu option ->  Select Package Sources  -> Click on the checkbox of  nuget.org  package. -> Click OK 

Now right click on Project -> Click on Manage NuGet Packages.
```